# SGX STEP building process

Tags: c#, c

I'm trying to implement sgx Foreshadow vulnerability follow the instruction contained in https://github.com/jovanbulck/sgx-step/tree/master/app/foreshadow

but I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../libsgxstep/libsgx-step.a(aep_trampoline.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `sgx_step_tcs' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:56: recipe for target 'app' failed
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

How can I implement this vulnerability?

Comment: If you want help with an error, you should post your code..

Comment: I wrote years ago in assembly language the code for a 486 Micro to go from unprotected mode to protected mode.I took me months of reading the Intel 486 hardware manual before I got all the bugs out of the code.The vulnerability you are trying to verify is the Protected mode features of the x86 micro's.It is very complicated and you must understand the x86 protected mode.Basically there are Segment Registers that prevents programs that are operating in one memory Segment to access other memory segments.Apparently when an exception occurs some data is left in the pipeline that can leak info.

Comment: Getting into Full Protected mode on x86 is a two step operation 1) Create a single security region for entire memory map of Micro (Kernel Mode) 2) Give each Process a separate limited Segment (memory area) so one process cannot access another process and an exception will occur when a process goes outside its limits.  The vulnerability is when an exception occurs you go from full protected mode to Kernel Mode where you have a single memory block and can access the pipeline registers.